# TFS2013: A service host may only be active on one machine at a time

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

On my tfs server 2013 update 3 I have the follow error:

Exception Message: ***The build service host HOSTNAME is currently owned by HOSTNAME. A service host may only be active on one machine at a time***. (type BuildServiceHostOwnershipException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.StartOperation.End(IAsyncResult result, HttpRouter& router, TfsMessageQueue& messageQueue, List`1& processHosts, MachineLifecycleActivity& traceActivity)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.EndStart(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Machine.WindowsService.EndStartMachine(IAsyncResult result)

I have not understand the problem.

Comment: I've seen this on ocassion in my TFS installation as well. Seems to happen after a reboot. If I can get more info, I'll pass it along.

Comment: I have the same event, but I'm not sure if it's harmless as it seems, given the builds still work just fine.

Comment: I'm using TFS update 5 and I see it too.  Everything seems to be working. All build defs I have created are running.